# Block Skype on Cisco IOS

Tags: networking, cisco, ios, qos, skype

I'm trying to block skype via policy routing but it's not working ... here's my configuration:

```
class-map match-any block
 match protocol skype

policy-map QoS-Priority-Input
class block
    police 1000000 31250 31250 conform-action drop  exceed-action drop  violate-action drop 

policy-map QoS-Priority-Output
class block
    police 1000000 31250 31250 conform-action drop  exceed-action drop  violate-action drop 

interface FastEthernet4
 description WAN
 service-policy input QoS-Priority-Input
 service-policy output QoS-Priority-Output
```

Answer (score 4):

`match protocol skype` will only match Skype Protocol v1.

v2 of the protocol is very good at finding ways around any blocks - for example it will simply use HTTPS if it has to.

Here is a very good description of how to block it by forcing it to use HTTPS and then using DPI to inspect and block Skype HTTPS traffic

http://www.scribd.com/doc/28067970/Blocking-Skype-Using-IOS

Answer (score 1):

If Skype behaves like a lot of P2P protocols, you're probably better off allocating it the smallest bandwidth allocation you can rather than outright blocking it. When faced with a complete block, they tend to negotiate new ports, but faced with a very choked channel, they stay in it.